# Pearl gold vs flat dark gold

Tags: piece-information, colour

I've ordered 4 "pearl gold" pieces of part [92690](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92690#T=C) on BrickLink. Unfortunately, the seller had to adjust the order as he only had 3 such pieces, he proposed adding two more in "flat dark gold" in exchange, which I agreed to.

However, searching the BrickLink database, no such piece exists in flat dark gold in any set (the seller acknowledged that and he has no other explanation).

These are the pieces (pearl gold on the left, flat dark gold on the right):

[image: gold pieces]

My question: What is the origin of the flat dark gold pieces? Is this discoloring because of age? Or is the BrickLink database in error? Note that, at the time of writing this, 70 sellers are offering this piece in flat dark gold.

Comment: Weird, BrickLink lists [Flat Dark Gold as in use from 2003 to 2007](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp?utm_content=subnav) but [part 92690 as starting in 2011](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=98167#T=C)

Answer (score 6):

There has been a slight change to the Pearl Gold/Warm Gold color recently that might explain the difference in color between those pieces. See [this article on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lego/comments/8xjtm0/are_all_four_of_these_pearl_gold_top_two_look/). Perhaps the right two “Flat Dark Gold” pieces are the newer recolor of Pearl Gold? I recall Jang from JangBricks talking about this as well in his videos.

Here is the picture from the Reddit article showing the new Pearl Gold on the top, and the old on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Can't decide if this is the correct answer or not. It certainly is interesting... would need a couple of those pearl gold new pieces to compare... I'm inclined to think the flat dark gold is less shiny than the elements presented here, but that could just be lightening.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve check out the Pearl Gold/Warm Gold color picture on [this page](https://brickset.com/colours/type-Pearl) and then compare it with your pieces. Do you see how within the Pearl Gold family the color hues and marble effects change significantly?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that so many sellers have it and named the color consistently pretty much rules out discoloration.

As to why the item isn't on BrickLink (or Brickset), I can only see the following explanation:

- it's in a set which hasn't been inventoried yet (but your seller would probably have known which one)
- it's been produced for something else which hasn't been inventoried for whatever reason - like the special Halloween elements in the minifigure walls in LEGO stores, for example... or some kind of Ninjago book (it does look Ninjagoesque to me), maybe not all of these have been inventoried
- I don't think that happens anymore nowadays, but it could have been produced specially for something not even public, such has LEGOland parks

I think the only way to know is to ask vendors; out of the 70 there must be one who knows. I contacted one in France but he has no clue either - he was intrigued too when finding them and was never able to find where they came from. He does believe it to be discolouration due to aging. I still don't; but maybe pearl gold 
acts differently than other colours.